# White bar at the top of ocean WP page (Elementor)

Tags: wordpress, themes, menubar, elementor, margins

There is a white bar at the top of my page (Ocean WP theme). I have disabled topbar in the the theme settings, so it should not be there because of that. I also have not found any global margin settings or similar. It can't be my header either, because my header is semitransparent and this white bar covers content if I move it further up on the page. If anyone knows what's going on there any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]